# Setting VCS branch via snapshot dependency in TeamCity

Tags: git, teamcity

I have a pair of Git repos that are used in a TeamCity build configuration.  If a build is triggered in the first repo, I need to run a command which determines which branch from the second repo should be used for the build (this is a non-trivial, and requires calling the GitHub API).

However, this can't be done as a build step (by then the VCS branches have already been determined), so instead, the main build configuration has a snapshot dependency on another build configuration (called `Setup`) which runs the command and modifies a configuration parameter called `RepoBranch` by outputting the following to stdout (for example):

`##teamcity[setParameter name='RepoBranch' value='refs/pull/12/merge']`

Then, in the main build configuration I have:

1. Created the `RepoBranch` parameter and set it to `%dep.Setup.RepoBranch%`.
2. In the VCS Root configuration page for the second repo, set the `Default branch` to `%RepoBranch%`

If I trigger the build, the snapshot dependency works fine, and I see the `RepoBranch` configuration parameter has been updated in both the Setup build configuration and the main build configuration.

However, the `master` branch of the second repo is still being checked out and used instead of the branch name specified by the `RepoBranch` parameter.

This appears to be because both `teamcity.build.vcs.branch.RepoName` and `teamcity.git.build.vcs.branch.RepoName` configuration parameters actually used in the build are still `refs/heads/master`.  Is this because I have the branch specification field for the second repo set to `+:refs/heads/master` perhaps? How to set this up correctly?

Comment: Why do you have a branch specification on the second vcs root if this isn't triggered directly (you're not monitoring for commits). The specification field can be empty if you're explicitly setting the default branch each time - It's really only of use when you want to trigger builds by monitoring multiple branches. When you say "If I trigger the build..." do you mean you commit to a branch in the first repository, or you click "Run build" in TC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of experimentation, it turns out that TeamCity enforces that all build configurations with snapshot dependencies use exactly the same VCS versions.  This is true even if the initial build configuration doesn't include the VCS root for which you want to change the branch on, so I guess TeamCity has already decided that the default branch is going to be used for all VCS roots other than the one which triggered the build.

In the end, the only solution seems to be to just go back to a single build configuration, and then add a build step at the start which switches branches where necessary (requires client-side checkout of sources).   If SSH authentication is used, the TeamCity `SSH agent` Build Feature can be used to authenticate the necessary `git` (or `svn`) commands.

To allow for the fact that other build steps may be using various TeamCity configuration parameters which contain the branch name and head revision, the initial build step should override these parameters by outputing the following values to `stdout`:

`// Override all TeamCity parameters which contain the branch name
printfn "##teamcity[setParameter name='teamcity.build.vcs.branch.%s' value='%s']" repoName branchName
printfn "##teamcity[setParameter name='teamcity.git.build.vcs.branch.%s' value='%s']" repoName branchName
// Override all TeamCity parameters which contain the SHA
printfn "##teamcity[setParameter name='build.vcs.number.%s' value='%s']" repoName sha
printfn "##teamcity[setParameter name='system.build.vcs.number.%s' value='%s']" repoName sha
printfn "##teamcity[setParameter name='env.BUILD_VCS_NUMBER_%s' value='%s']" repoName sha`

where `branchName` is the new branch that was switched to on the repo called `repoName`, and `sha` is the SHA of the head of that branch.